# How can i simply achieve Sencha-Like class inheritance in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, sencha-touch, extjs, underscore.js

I'm starting a new Backbone app, and I've been quite fond of the javascript class inheritance system of Sencha Touch 2.0, basically i want to be able to do this :

```
Helium.define('Application', {
    namespace: 'Helium',
    constructor: function() {
        console.warn('Helium');
    }
});

Helium.define('Application', {
    namespace: 'MyApp',
    extend: 'Backbone.Events',
    routers: ['Cards'],
    constructor: function() {
        console.warn(this);
        this.callParent();
        console.warn('MyApp');
        //console.warn(Helium.getDisplayName(arguments.callee));
    }
});
```

I'm stuck on the prototype chain definition (to make the this.callParent() work) :

```
        var p = Object.create(extend);
        var o = _.extend(p, data);
        /*function() {
            var _o = _.extend(p, data);
            _o.constructor.apply(o, arguments);
            return _o;
        };*/
        o.prototype.superclass = p;
        o.prototype.callParent = function() {
            console.warn(p);
        };
```

Here is the complete micro-implementation so far :

So far, i have done this :

```
_.mixin({
    resolve : function(path, base, separator) {
        var parts = path.split('.' || separator),
            key = parts.pop();
            base = base || window;

        while (parts.length) {
            part = parts.shift();
            base = base[part] = base[part] || {};
        }
        base[key] = base[key] || {};

        return base[key];
}});

Helium = {

    define: function(className, data) {

        var base = window,
            extend = data.extend || {constructor : function() {}},
            namespace = data.namespace || null;

        if(namespace) {
            window[namespace] = window[namespace] || {};
            base = window[namespace];
        }

        if(_.isString(extend)) extend = _.resolve(extend);
        if(!extend) throw 'Extend error';

        var parts = className.split('.'),
            key = parts.pop();
        while (parts.length) {
            part = parts.shift();
            base = base[part] = base[part] || {};
        }

        delete data.extend;
        //delete data.namespace;
        data.$name = key;
        data.$className = className;

        var p = Object.create(extend);
        var o = _.extend(p, data);
        /*function() {
            var _o = _.extend(p, data);
            _o.constructor.apply(o, arguments);
            return _o;
        };*/
        o.prototype.superclass = p;
        o.prototype.callParent = function() {
            console.warn(p);
        };

    },

    getDisplayName: function(callee) {
        console.warn('getDisplayName', [this, arguments]);
        console.warn(callee.toString());

    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're going for here but if your end game is really being able to call the parent constructor I think it's a little convoluted to try and impose Sencha's inheritance model on Backbone because it is so simple and lightweight and ultimately it has its own inheritance implementation.

Since Backbone's `extend()` only exists on Backbone classes I think [this](http://blog.usefunnel.com/2011/03/js-inheritance-with-backbone/) is a good resource. Unless I'm misunderstanding you I think something along the lines of `MyApp.__super__.initialize()` in Backbone would be roughly equivalent to `this.callParent()` in Sencha Touch.

Comment: I guess you are right and it is a waste to force another inheritance pattern into backbone. I'll keep Backbone extending system.

Comment: I'm going to ask a new specific q about a this.callParent() implementation in backbone (because i do hate the static MyApp.__super__.methodName thing!).

Comment: Your new question definitely clarifies your intent. I'm with you on that, and I'll be thinking about a solution. Hopefully something a little simpler than what you proposed but who knows.